# Why is "i" variable getting incremented twice in my program?

Tags: c, macros

One of my friend showed me this program and asked me why is `i` variable getting incremented twice.

According to my understanding `MAX(i++, ++j);` in this line `i` is first send as a parameter and then incremented, so if the initial value of `i` is `10` then the incremented value should be `11`, but it shows the incremented value of `i` as `12`.

**Program :**

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX(x,y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)

void main(void)
{
    int i = 10;
    int j = 5;
    int k = 0;

    k = MAX(i++, ++j);

    printf("%d %d %d",i,j,k);
}
```

**Output :**

> 12 6 11

Can someone please explain me how is the value incremented to 12 ?

Thanks.

Comment: Also remember that `main` should return an `int`!

Comment: Surely, this must be a duplicate of some earlier question?

Comment: @larsmans It might me and I even don't know what exactly to search for this kind of problem.

Comment: It's a good question. I'm just surprised that I couldn't find the duplicate myself and apparently no-one else found it either.

Comment: Dont use Macro for Ternary operator expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your macro substitution means that you write `(i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j)`.

Answer (score 8):

`MAX` is a macro, not a function.  In your use case, it expands to:

```
k = (i++) > (++j) ? (i++) : (++j);
```

Answer (score 5):

Your macro definition contains the arguments twice

```
#define MAX(x,y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)
```

Which makes

```
 k = MAX(i++, ++j);
```

expand to

```
k = (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(j++);
```

And thus, increments twice.

Answer (score 4):

`MAX` is not a function. `i` is not send as a parameter.

`MAX` is a macro. It is text-replaced where it's used:

```
k = (i++)>(j++)?(i++):(j++)
```

Now you know why it is incremented twice.

Answer (score 2):

Macro do simple text substitution, so after macro expansion, the `k = MAX(i++, ++j);` line is seen by the compiler as :

```
k = (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `MAX` macro expands to

```
(i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j)
```

showing why you get a double increment.

Answer (score 2):

The macro will be expanded to something like in pseudo-C code :

```
if( i++ > j++)  // i is incremented the first time,  j is incremented once
   return i++;  // i is incremented the second time
else
   return j++;  // we never go there, so j is not incremented twice
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `MAX(i++, ++j)`, the generated code will be :

```
(i++) > (++j) ? (i++) : (++j)
```

Using preprocessor macro just expand the code and copy/paste the arguments in place. You might want to use a function for this case.

```
int max(int x, int y)
{
  return (x > y ? x : y);
}
```

Modern compiler will inline it while respecting the original behavior of the function call.