# Why is “i” variable not getting incremented twice in my program?

Tags: c, macros

[Why is "i" variable getting incremented twice in my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885105/why-is-i-variable-getting-incremented-twice-in-my-program)

I modified the question but why is the output different. shouldn't it be same?.?

Code :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX(x,y) (x)>(y)?(x):(y)
void main(void)
{
    int i = 10;
    int j = 5;
    int k = 0;
    k == MAX(i++, ++j);
    printf("%d %d %d",i,j,k);
}
```

Output :-
    11 7 0

Shouldnt the output be 12 6 0

Comment: I think this is undefined behaviour, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points

Comment: Isn't the ternary sequenced?

Comment: @ammoQ It is not. The conditional operator has a sequence point between the condition and the evauluation of the 2nd or 3rd operand

Comment: I stand corrected ;-)

Comment: Even if the macro didn't do weird things, `k == MAX(i++, ++j);` doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `>` operator in the macro, and not the `<`?

Comment: Check whether the operator is > or < in your macro

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is `>`, see my answer :)

Comment: +1 btw, because it is funny to see how many of our C gurus that failed to immediately point out why the results turned out as they did, yours sincerely included :) Once you properly expand the whole line of code and not just the macro, it all becomes clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the macro expands into this:

```
k == i++ > ++j ? i++ : ++j;
```

Operator precedence dictates that > has higher prio than == which has higher prio than ?:
So the above is equivalent to this:

```
(k == (i++ > ++j)) ? i++ : ++j;
```

`i++` and `++j` are executed first. Since `i++ > j++` gets evaluated to true (1), we get this:

```
(k == 1) ? i++ : ++j;
```

Then since k is 0, `k == 1` is evaluated to false (0). We get:

```
0 ? i++ : ++j;
```

And therefore ++j is executed once more.

---

(As a side note, this expression is well-defined, because the conditional operator has a sequence point between the condition and the evauluation of the 2nd or 3rd operand.)

Comment: You deserve a pizza bro

Answer (score 5):

Use braces around your macro definitions:

```
#define MAX(x,y) ( (x)>(y)?(x):(y) )
```

The expanded expression (with the original macro definition)

```
k == (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j);
```

groups as

```
(k == i++ > ++j) ? i++ : ++j;
```

`i++ > ++j` evaluates to `1`, which is unequal to `k` (`k` is 0), so the third operand of `?:` (`++j`) is evaluated. So, `i` is incremented once, `j` twice, and `k` wasn’t changed since its initialization, hence your output.

Answer (score 2):

```
k == MAX(i++, ++j);
```

is replaced as

```
k == (i++)>(++j)?(i++):(++j);
```

Here `i=10`,`j=5`. so

```
k == (10++)>(6)?(11++):(++6);
```

so it that expression while checking condition `i` is incremented once after checking the condition due to post increment and `j` also incremented once. But `10 > 6` condition is true.

```
(k == 1 )?(i++):(++j); // here i=11 and j=6

(k == 1 )? (11++):(++6);
```

so here `k==1` condition fails. it will not evaluate `i++` in that expression, it will evaluate `++j` and return it. here `i` is remains 11 and `j` become 7.

So you will get 11 7 0 as output.